# how to loop div section which is inside repeater control using c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using a repeater control with multiple `<div>`, I am getting all the values except comments.

div fetches only single record. Inspite of repeater the values are not looping. Is there any solution where I can repeat that comments section?

Any help please?

My markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_post" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_post_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="user-thumb">
            <img src='<%# Eval("Profile_Pic") %>'  class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="user-information">
            <p><%# Eval("Name") %> </p>
            <small><%# Eval("Timestamp") %> </small>
            <asp:Label ID="lblpost_id" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("Post_Id") %>' > 
            </asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="comment col-md-12">//this section is not repeating
            <h4>taruni </h4>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblcomment" Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void rpt_post_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT pc.Comment, pc.Post_Id FROM Post_Comment pc INNER JOIN Posts kp ON kp.Post_Id = pc.Post_Id WHERE pc.Post_Id = @postid";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postid", postid);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            con.Open();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Label lblcom = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblcomment");
                lblcom.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Comment"].ToString();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the repeater

this is your code

```
               if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Label lblcom = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblcomment");
                    lblcom.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Comment"].ToString();
                }
```

You are setting the text of that label to the first comment.  That is why you are only seeing one comment.

you probably want something that looks like this:

```
    rpt_post.DataSource = dt;  
    rpt_post.DataBind();
```

Also
This

```
select pc.Comment,pc.Post_Id 
from Post_Comment pc
INNER JOIN Posts kp on kp.Post_Id=pc.Post_Id 
 where pc.Post_Id=@postid;
```

is the same as this

```
select pc.Comment,pc.Post_Id 
from Post_Comment pc
where pc.Post_Id=@postid;
```

Comment: i have some code which i have not posted ..i have some conditions thats why put inner join condition

Comment: @WebFunda-- well that could matter since the "conditions" could cause only one row to be returned... make sure you test your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Put the datarow in a DataRowView then get/set your comment

```
  //put in row datarow view
  DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

  //get your label
  Label lblcom = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblcomment");

  //set the label 
  lblcom.Text = dataRow["Comment"].ToString();
```